# bootstrap navbar collapses on the first click or touch on a mobile screen

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have a responsive site that uses css bootstrap navbar .

The problems is , on a mobile phone any tap/click/touch anywhere on the screen makes the navbar collapse . On the second tap/click/touch the navbar goes back . On a desktop screen the behavior is similar but it only results in a flick or refresh of the screen , which is still not intended .

The intended behavior is , the navbar should only collapse on a tap/click/touch to the navbar icon on the top right corner .

Any help on fixing this ?

OK, here's the code...

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="navbar-header">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#XX-header-1">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>    
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
    <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand visible-xs" href="/home"><img src="XXXX" class="img-responsive" /></a>
  <a class="navbar-brand hidden-xs" href="/home">Home</a>
</div>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="cb-header-1">

  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

    <li <?php XXX ?> ><a href="/XXX">XXX</a></li>
    <li <?php YYY ?> ><a href="/YYY">YYY</a></li> 

  <?php if (a==b) { ?>

    <li class="active" >
    <a href="<?php AAA ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>
    <?php
    SOME CODE HERE
    ?>
    </a>
    </li>
    <li class="active" >
    <a href="/MMM"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span> MMM</a></li>

  <?php } else { ?>

    <li <?php NNN ?> ><a href="/NNN"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> NNN</a></li>
    <li <?php OOO ?> ><a href="/OOO"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> OOO</a></li>

  <?php } ?>

  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
</nav>
```

Here's the CSS for the nav bar customization

```
.navbar-default {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-color: #COLOR1;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: #COLOR2;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
    color: #COLOR3;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-text {
    color: #COLOR2;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #COLOR2;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    color: #COLOR3;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    color: #COLOR3;
    background-color: #COLOR1;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
    color: #COLOR3;
    background-color: #COLOR1;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: #COLOR1;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
    background-color: #COLOR1;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: #COLOR2;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse, .navbar-default .navbar-form {
    border-color: #COLOR2;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-link {
    color: #COLOR2;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-link:hover {
    color: #COLOR3;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
        color: #COLOR2;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
        color: #COLOR3;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
        color: #COLOR3;
        background-color: #COLOR1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like one of the elements (probably the toggle button) isn't being closed, or is wrapping more elements than it should. Could you provide the HTML in question? Or perhaps a jsFiddle? It will be hard to diagnose the problem without a little more information.

`EDIT:`[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5rLtqfkw/)

Comment: thx for your response . I've edited the question and added html code .

Comment: Well, I can't see any obvious problems with the HTML. It all works if dropped into a fiddle (assuming #XX-header-1 is #cb-header-1) and doesn't show any unusual behaviors.
It looks likely the odd behavior is coming from elsewhere, it would be worth looking through your scripts to make sure nothing else might be triggering bootstrap's collapse.

Comment: Thx again, now I've edited the question and added the navbar customization CSS code, if it helps.

Comment: Now, there are java scripts , but none that interact with the navbar . there is jquery for pagination,calendar used from the standard download and there are custom js that do screen level validation.

Comment: @ench, why not post your fiddle for the rest of us to use?

Answer (score 0):

The following code in a js file was causing this , took out the code , it started working the way it was suppose to, thx to all for helping out

$(document).on('click',function(){    $('.collapse').collapse('hide'); })

Comment: Where was this piece of code. did u have a custom js or this code is from bootstrap.js ?